# Stop image going on next line on small device

Tags: html, css

My timer image goes on next line of the page when i look thru mobile device and i wanna stop that...only using css
I have 2 images logo and timer. the problem is when i see my header on small device the timer image goes on next line..and it looks weird.

```
<header class="mainheader">
        <div>
            <img src="/images/logo.png">
            <img src="/images/timer.png" class="timerimg">
        </div>
</header>
.maiheader{
    height: 4em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding-top: 0.9em;
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-right:2em;
}

.timerimg{
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: How do you want to stop it? You want to keep scrolling across or change the size?

If you're designing something for mobile I would recommend you make use of media queries.

Comment: i want UI to stop at the point when the 2nd image goes down...i can use media queries but i think it is also possible by using some simple stuff

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display both images in one line then  you can  structure your code like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
.maiheader{
    height: 4em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding-top: 0.9em;
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-right:2em;
}

.logo{
    float:left;
width:50%;
}

.timer{
    float:left;
width:50%;
}
img
{
width:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header class="mainheader">
        <div>
<div class="logo">
            <img src="http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg"></div>
           <div class="timer"> <img src="http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg"></div>
        </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <body onresize="demo()">
      <header class="mainheader">
        <div>
             <img src="/images/logo.png" id="logo0">
             <img src="/images/timer.png" id="logo1"class="timerimg">
        </div>
 </header>
 <style>

   .maiheader{
       height: 4em;
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      padding-top: 0.9em;
      padding-left: 2em;
      padding-right:2em;
             }

 .timerimg  {
     float:right;
            }
 </style>
 <script>
    function demo(){
          var logo1 = document.getElementById("logo1").style;
          var logo0 = document.getElementById("logo0").style;
if(innerWidth < 358){logo1.marginTop="-238";}else{logo1.marginTop="0";}
                    }
 </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: try this one  best answer

Comment: appreciate ur efforts but i want only use of css...i will update my question...thanksss

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help you some

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 49%;
  
  max-width: 49%;
 
  display: inline-block;
  
}
.logo {
  background: url('https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png') no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 33.82%;
  /* (img-height / img-width * width) */
  background-size: contain;
}
.timer {
  background: url('https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png') no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 33.82%;
  /* (img-height / img-width * width) */
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<header class="mainheader">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="logo"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="timer"></div>
  </div>
</header>
```